# Can't get class of model - Maybe cache problem?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cache, ce-1.9.2.4, getmodel

I'm following a video tutorial on Magento for developers and I'm quite a beginner at this. I'm currently using `Magento CE 1.9.2.4`.

I created a simple dummy module which controller works fine. Although, when I add a model and try to get its class, the controller action I use to `get_class` just gives no result (empty page). If I add an echo before that line I can see the message correctly.

Things I've tried so far:

- checked other similar Q&A but I don't seem to have made the same mistakes
- reset all files chmods to 664 and all folders to 755
- reset all chowns to the standard user:group
- disable and re-enable module output from the Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced section
- re-watched the tutorial steps over and over

I'm out of options now. Seeing the controller working (index and phpinfo actions work fine) it seems like there's a problem in the model itself but I can't find it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 1**

After roughly an hour of checking around for a solution I just refreshed the page and it worked.

This raises even more questions because since I started developing days ago I immediately disabled then purged all caches in the admin and also tried opening the page in browser's private mode many many times with no success.

So it seems like there's *something else* caching the page, not magento nor my browser. What could it be?

**END OF EDIT 1**

Some details to follow.

> Module tree structure:

[image: Module tree]

> ./etc/modules/Disc_Prova.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- app/etc/modules/Disc_Prova.xml -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Disc_Prova>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Disc_Prova>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> ./app/code/local/Disc/Prova/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- app/code/local/Disc/Prova/etc/config.xml -->
<config>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <Disc_Prova>
                <class>Disc_Prova_Block</class>
            </Disc_Prova>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <Disc_Prova>
                <class>Disc_Prova_Helper</class>
            </Disc_Prova>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <Disc_Prova>
                <class>Disc_Prova_Model</class>
            </Disc_Prova>
        </models>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <disc_prova>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Disc_Prova</module>
                    <frontName>prova</frontName>
                </args>
            </disc_prova>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

> ./app/code/local/Disc/Prova/controllers/IndexController.php:

```
<?php

class Disc_Prova_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Works!';
    }

    public function modelAction()
    {
        // Adding this line shows the text correctly
        //echo "blabla1";
        echo get_class(Mage::getModel('Disc_Prova/Roba'));
        // Adding this line shows the text correctly
        //echo "blabla2";
    }

    public function phpinfoAction()
    {
        phpinfo();
    }
}
```

> ./app/code/local/Disc/Prova/Model/Roba.php:

```
<?php
// app/code/local/Disc/Prova/Model/Roba.php

class Disc_Prova_Model_Roba extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract 
{

}
```

> Result with commented echo(s):

[image: result no echo]

> Result with uncommented echo(s):

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I created a new module, `Atest_Module`:

[image]

> ./app/etc/modules/Atest_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <atest_module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </atest_module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> ./app/code/local/Atest/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- app/code/local/Atest/Module/etc/config.xml -->
<config>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <atest_module>
                <class>Atest_Module_Block</class>
            </atest_module>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <atest_module>
                <class>Atest_Module_Helper</class>
            </atest_module>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <atest_module>
                <class>Atest_Module_Model</class>
            </atest_module>
        </models>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <atest_module>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Atest_Module</module>
                    <frontName>atest</frontName>
                </args>
            </atest_module>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

> ./app/code/local/Atest/Module/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class Atest_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Works!';
    }

    public function modelAction()
    {
        // Adding this line shows the text correctly
        //echo "blabla1";
        echo get_class(Mage::getModel('atest_module/roba'));
        // Adding this line shows the text correctly
        //echo "blabla2";
    }

    public function phpinfoAction()
    {
        phpinfo();
    }
}
```

> ./app/code/local/Atest/Module/Model/Roba.php

```
<?php

class Atest_Module_Model_Roba extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract 
{

}
```

> Now the controller isn't even hit. I bet if I try in an hour it will work..?

[image]

**END OF EDIT 2**

**EDIT 3**

After changing the module declaration in **/app/etc/modules/Atest_Module.xml** to Capitalized, the module works immediately. So at the end, apart from the upper/lower case mishap, I think deleting **var/cache** made the module appear immediately.

**END OF EDIT 3**

Comment: Have you tried like below

    `$obj = Mage::getModel('Disc_Prova/Roba');`
    `echo get_class($obj);`

Comment: Same result, blank page.

Comment: There's some developments, updating the question...

Comment: Please check error log if any logs has been made there for error. Also enable Magento's log from System=>Configuration=>Developer tab. That will add log to magento's var/log directory

Comment: i test ur code i can't find problem with that is showing this out `Disc_Prova_Model_Roba` on url `prova/index/model` make sure you clear ur cache or disabled it

Comment: See edit 1, @QaisarSatti. It seems like some caching problem but I don't see where it comes from. It's not Magento's cache.

Comment: your `<models>
            <Disc_Prova>
                <class>Disc_Prova_Model</class>
            </Disc_Prova>
        </models>` this part of config.xml is not updated i think so it is cache problem.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Good, but how can I force it to refresh then, since Magento's cache is already disabled? Should I restart some services on the machine?

Comment: @GigiSan if your cache is not refreshed delete the cache folder  from `var/cache`. disabling will do trick for me always don't know why this happens to you.

Comment: Thanks @QaisarSatti. I will test the folder deletion with fschmengler 's answer to see who's right :)

Comment: @GigiSan fschmengler's answer is correct you must use the lower case so it's not look weird but using in upper case can't create problem. it will work with both.

Comment: Tried to create a new module and I get 404 on every page. Tried deleting var/cache and nothing has changed. Oddly enough, the model class of the disc_prova doesn't show anymore. Should we move the discussion to chat? Granted you can and want to. :)

Comment: i added the updated kind check and feedback if you have any problem with that.

Comment: See edit 2, added new module

Comment: after seeing this you have added the lower case where upper needed kindly compare with my answer and then you will find your mistakes

Comment: See edit 3, the problem is solved but apart from the case problems, deleting var/cache did the trick. Feel free to post the asnwer and I'll accpet it or I will write one myself later :) Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: After days of trouble, turns out the problem was PHP's OPcache! See my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your module configuration

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- app/etc/modules/Disc_Prova.xml -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Disc_Prova>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Disc_Prova>
    </modules>
</config>
```

your config.xml with changes you have to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- app/code/local/Disc/Prova/etc/config.xml -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Disc_Prova>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Disc_Prova>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <disc_prova>
                <class>Disc_Prova_Block</class>
            </disc_prova>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <disc_prova>
                <class>Disc_Prova_Helper</class>
            </disc_prova>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <disc_prova>
                <class>Disc_Prova_Model</class>
            </disc_prova>
        </models>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <disc_prova>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Disc_Prova</module>
                    <frontName>prova</frontName>
                </args>
            </disc_prova>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

your controller

```
    <?php

class Disc_Prova_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Works!';
    }

    public function modelAction()
    {
        // Adding this line shows the text correctly
        //echo "blabla1";
        echo get_class(Mage::getModel('disc_prova/roba'));
        // Adding this line shows the text correctly
        //echo "blabla2";
    }

    public function phpinfoAction()
    {
        phpinfo();
    }
}
```

you model

```
 <?php
// app/code/local/Disc/Prova/Model/Roba.php

class Disc_Prova_Model_Roba extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract 
{

}
```

> At the end delete `cache` folder in  `var/cache`

Answer (score 2):

It should be `Mage::getModel('Disc‌​_Prova/roba');`

Explanation:

the first part (`Disc_Prova`) is the alias you defined in config.xml:

```
<models>
    <Disc_Prova>                           <---- HERE
        <class>Disc_Prova_Model</class>
    </Disc_Prova>
</models>
```

the second part (`roba`) is what follows after the prefix

```
<models>
    <Disc_Prova>
        <class>Disc_Prova_Model</class> <--- PREFIX
    </Disc_Prova>
</models>
```

**but in lower case!**

This looks less weird if you follow the convention to make the module aliases lower case as well:

```
    <models>
        <disc_prova>
            <class>Disc_Prova_Model</class>
        </disc_prova>
    </models>
```

Then it's `Mage::getModel('disc_prova/roba')`

Comment: I have doubts about this answer, both because the tutorial shows capitalized XML tags (and its demo works) and because this should have never worked (see edit 1). I will try to develop a brand new module following your convention to see if it works straight away. If it doesn't I'll try delete var/cache as suggested in the question's comments. Thanks for your time nonetheless.

Comment: You're right, it is non-standard but will still work because when Magento transforms it to CamelCase, the class name is correct. I overlooked the fact that it suddenly worked.

Comment: I think that is not causing the problem..

Comment: Still, I would not trust a beginners tutorial that does not follow basic naming conventions

Comment: Shush! We're talking about the official "Fundamentals of Magento Development" course! :D I'm joking... I find it quite slippery in some points too, and I know nothing about the subject :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer for completion. 
The main problem that caused me to ask this question was due to the presence of a cached version in `<magento root>/var/cache`. Deleting that folder solved the problem.

There were some upper/lower case mishaps in the middle but they were not causing the original problem.

Thanks to @Qaisar Satti and @fschmengler for their precious help!

**EDIT:**

After applying all the suggestion in the other answers, I was still repeatedly having caching problems in the order of minutes for every single page. Investigating further I found that the very **core** of the problem was that the PHP module `OPcache` was enabled on my web server.

I disabled it by editing `php.ini` by replacing

```
opcache.enable=1
```

with

```
opcache.enable=0
```

Now, after **days** of torment, I can finally hit that `F5` with serenity. What a relief.